# Modelling database entites using text only

Tags: modeling

Back in the day, there was a standard that I was taught a standard for modelling database entities using text only, I can't remember the name of the standard but it looked somehing like

**TableName**, *Key*, Column

Anybody know what that form was called?

Answer (score 0):

Is [flat-file model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_file_database) the term you're looking for?